# GSA Search Result count difference for Sort by date Vs Sort by relevance

Tags: google-search-appliance

When we search for any term in GSA the **result count** for **Sort by date** ***Vs*** **Sort by relevance** are not same. Is this is default behavior of GSA? Any help would be of a great help.

Thanks,
Manju

Answer (score 0):

Result count in GSA is an estimate rather than a actual count. you can force GSA to give accurate count by adding rc parameter in your query. Using this you can get accurate result count for upto 1M documents. You can read more about GSA result counting [here](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/current/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/appendices.html#1075478)

I am not sure why result count for sort by date and sort by relevance varies.Try to add rc param in both the queries and see if that helps you.

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: Thanks for the info and link @Mohan kumar, I wanted to know if its a default behavior, just wanted to check with others who use GSA. is the result count is same or different for you ?

Comment: Are you using date of the document(Last modifed date) to sort out? and is your count getting reduced while applying sort by date?

Comment: Yes that's correct, we are using last modified date. 
So the Sort by date is giving less records compared to Sort by relevance.

Comment: I just removed date from documents and have applied sort by date but unfortunately I don't see any discrepancy in count .:(

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mohan kumar. Will post my findings here.